# MySQL Foreign key skip checking fail - [Error code: 1025]

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_category_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Parent category ID store in the same table',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_category_category_id_idx` (`parent_category_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_category_category_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_category_id`)
    REFERENCES `touriable`.`category` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

And I am going to run the following SQL:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

ALTER TABLE category CHANGE parent_category_id parent_category_id INT;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

But I got the error message:

```
Error Code: 1025. Error on rename of './#sql-1260_d9b775' to './category' (errno: 150)  0.312 sec
```

I have really no idea about why I cannot run the SQL. I have tried to skip foreign key checking but still fail. Why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column types must match: an INT column can't be the foreign key for an unsigned INT column. Try:

```
ALTER TABLE category CHANGE parent_category_id parent_category_i INT UNSIGNED;
```